# How to make an object follow another object's path in Unity3D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, path-finding, rigid-bodies

I've tried asking this question on the Unity answers site, but since I've yet to receive an answer I figured I'd ask this question here as well. I am trying to make a 3D version of the game "Snake", but I am running into serious problems trying to make the first snake segment follow the head of the snake. The GameObjects I am using are spheres with rigidbody components, with the player having control only over the "head" of the snake. Then, as the snake grows, more spheres are added that should follow the path that the main sphere makes.

I would like to know if there is either a more elegant solution to what I am trying to achieve, or at least a little help into what I may do to fix the current implementation. I am attaching the code of the segment that is supposed to follow the head. The naming for the objects are in Spanish, but it may not be that hard to figure out what is going on from a non-Spanish speaking person's perspective.

I have also properly commented the code, so that you can understand what I am doing at each sentence. The main idea that partially works right now is to send the snake segments information about where exactly the head made a turn so that when the segments get to a particular turning point, they can make a turn in the direction the head turned. The problem I have is that sometimes the segment travels past by the point where it should make a turn, and I don't understand if it is because of precision problems (I am making float comparisons to determine if a segment has reached a certain position where it turns) or if it's something else.

```
 using UnityEngine;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using Clases;

 public class ControladorSegmento : MonoBehaviour {

     //This is a generic list of Objects that store both turning position and turning direction that the head has made
     public List<PosicionCambioDireccion> listaPosicionesCambioDireccion;

     //This would be the head in the case of only one segment that is following
     public GameObject lider;

     //Speed
     public float rapidez;

     //Direction
     public Vector3 direccion;

     //This is an index that is used to iterate over the list of turning points
     private int indiceCambioDireccion;

     // Use this for initialization
     void Start () {

         indiceCambioDireccion = 0;

         listaPosicionesCambioDireccion = new List<PosicionCambioDireccion>();

         //First find the Head of the snake so that we can access its position in order to determine segment spawning position
         lider = GameObject.Find("Cabeza");

         //Set the position of the new segment 2 units right behind the head
         transform.position = lider.GetComponent<Transform>().position - lider.GetComponent<ControladorCabeza>().direccion * 2f;

         //Get the current direction of the head so that the segment inmediately moves in its direction
         direccion = lider.GetComponent<ControladorCabeza>().direccion;
     }

     void LateUpdate () {

         //Check if there has been a change in direction that the segment has to follow
         if ((listaPosicionesCambioDireccion.Count > 0) && (listaPosicionesCambioDireccion.Count > indiceCambioDireccion)) {

             //Compare how close we are to the turning position. If we are sufficiently close, change segment direction
             if (Mathf.Abs(transform.position.x - listaPosicionesCambioDireccion[indiceCambioDireccion].posicion.x) < 0.0999999 &&
                 Mathf.Abs(transform.position.z - listaPosicionesCambioDireccion[indiceCambioDireccion].posicion.z) < 0.0999999) {

                 //Change segment direction at the current position
                 direccion = listaPosicionesCambioDireccion[indiceCambioDireccion].direccion;

                 //Increment turning positions list index so that we get the next turning point in the list (if there is any)
                 indiceCambioDireccion++;
             }
         }
     }

     void FixedUpdate() {


         //Change the velocity
         GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = direccion * rapidez;

     }
 }
```

I am still really new working with Unity and it seems I have still much to learn. And again, if you have a more elegant solution to what I am trying to achieve, please let me know. Right know I am aware that this implementation could cause a sort of memory leak in the sense that, as long as the head keeps changing direction, the list of turning points that is stored is going to keep growing and growing which obviously is something one should avoid.

Answer (score 0):

You may record each segment's position in last frame in a list(include head), at the next frame, create a vector from the current position of the head segment to the last position recorded last frame. Then step the distance of the sum of both head & first segment's radius from the current position of the head, and place your first segment there. Repeat these steps for all other segments consist your snake. Hope this can help you.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. I was doing that, but if i directly control the positions of the spheres the movement looks wonky and ugly. I am looking for a solution that involves moving the spheres by modifying the actual velocity of the rigid body, as the moving animation is more fluid. Your recommended solution makes it look like the spheres are being teleported.

Comment: You can move the head by physics velocity but update other segments in Update() call every frame, this will make them fluid.